# Android WebView white page after restart activity

Tags: android, webview

I am using WebView to load a webpage in Android activity.

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Unlock(), "AndroidUnlock");
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo.html?ver=" + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

When the webview loaded, I pressed the back button to finish the activity.

And I launch the activity again, the webview load the webpage incorrectly. It shows a blank page to me.

How can I to fix the issue please?

If I use `System.exit(0)` to exit the activity, it works very well, the webview load the webpage correct again.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading the **URL** in `onCreate()`. Put the code (**except** `webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);`) in `onResume()` :

```
@Overrride
protected void onResume(){
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Unlock(), "AndroidUnlock");
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo.html?ver=" + System.currentTimeMillis());    
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please explain how does this help.